# Mobile Browsers and cache clearing

Tags: caching, mobile, browser

I have my web site style sheets setup with versions.  For desktop browsers, css changes to the style sheet are reflected immediately.

```
enter code here<link href="/media/templates/site/mytemplate/css/stye.css?v=1698161779" rel="stylesheet" class="">e
```

However, mobile browsers are a problem. I use Android and the Brave and Firefox browsers.  Style changes on the web site do not show up in the browser unless I clear the browser cache.

Is there any trick to force a mobile browser to use the latest version of the style sheet"?